# How does the browser know what font I want to use when they are all called Roboto?

Tags: css, font-face

This is such a noob question, but here goes...

I'm seeing a lot of examples using the following styling when loading fonts from local server:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    src: local(Roboto Thin),
        url("#{$roboto-font-path}Roboto-Thin.woff2") format("woff2"),
        url("#{$roboto-font-path}Roboto-Thin.woff") format("woff");
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    src: local(Roboto Medium),
        url("#{$roboto-font-path}Roboto-Light.woff2") format("woff2"),
        url("#{$roboto-font-path}Roboto-Light.woff") format("woff");
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
```

Notice that the `font-family` both are called Roboto.

How can I in my styling let my browser know that I want to use the Thin or the Medium font?

On other projects I've used `font-family: "Roboto Light"` when loading font from external page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it in your styling by defining the `font-weight` that is defined in the `@font-face`.

So when you want to use `"Roboto Thin"` set `font-weight: 100;` and for `"Roboto Medium"` set `font-weight: 500;` respectively.

Similarly, if you were to change the `font-style` inside the `@font-face` you can set your custom fonts for italics and bold.